# IONIC 5, unable to pass values to TS file with ngModel

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

need some help with IONIC 5..i want to add on click function to each of the ion item...i want a form to appear below when any of the raio item is clicked

I have tried to use  (ng-click)="selection(item.id)"
 and also tried

none seem to work as expected.

```
<div class="cat-holder">
        <ion-radio-group>
          <div class="rad-item" text-center>
            <ion-item text-center>
              <img src="assets/imgs/dstv.png" alt="">
              <ion-radio value="transport"></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-label>Item1</ion-label>
          </div>

          <div class="rad-item" text-center>
            <ion-item text-center>
              <img src="assets/imgs/bill1.svg" alt="">
              <ion-radio value="bill"></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-label>Item2</ion-label>
          </div>

        </ion-radio-group>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use (click)="method you want"
And in ionic 5, using text-center is deprecated,i think you can use class="ion-text-center" instead

In yours ts file:

```
export yourclass{
selectedValue:any;
}
```

In you html file:

```
<div class="cat-holder">
        <ion-radio-group>
          <div class="rad-item" text-center>
            <ion-item text-center>
              <img src="assets/imgs/dstv.png" alt="">
              <ion-radio [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"  value="transport"></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-label>Item1</ion-label>
          </div>

          <div class="rad-item" text-center>
            <ion-item text-center  >
              <img src="assets/imgs/bill1.svg" alt="">
              <ion-radio [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" value="bill"></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-label>Item2</ion-label>
          </div>

        </ion-radio-group>
  </div>

<div *ngIf="selectedValue=='value u want from radio"></div>
```

Comment: so how will i display a new div based on what is selected

Comment: got this error ---> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: Yeah ,i though you want to make as you said :(ng-click)="selection(item.id)" , so though you have this function

Comment: am not able to get it to work..dont know whats wrong..when i click nothing happens

Comment: In the ng if, check if selectedvalue=='transport'

Comment: Yes i did that and still nothing

Comment: If you remove <ion-radio-group> try if it work, forget about thr shape for now and just test it. If it work tell me.

Comment: Add a button and inside it add (click)="checkvalue()" and inside ts file add checkvalue(){console.log(this.seclectedValue);} and after tou select the radio click the button an see if it is taking the value or not.

Comment: it echoes (true) to console

Comment: first click echos undefined, second click and more clicks echoes true

Comment: Then its getting the value, now change in radio button [(ngModel)]="selectedValue='transport'" and the other bill then try and log , now it should work.

Comment: Cannot create property 'transport' on boolean 'true'

Comment: Then selectedvalue =='transport'

Comment: Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 28 in [selectedValue =='transport'=$event]

Comment: Ok in this way it will not grt thr value, thr selected value is getting bool state of the radio, if your form is just 2 selects, then define 2 selectvlaues in ts file and put ngif selectedvalue1 == true then its transport and ngif selectedvalue2 ==bill , or you can bind your ion-radio-grou in form group and give each div a formcontrolname and get the form .value.

Comment: can u share ur skype pls?

Comment: Right now i don't have skype sinc emy computer is far from me, this is my whatsapp 0096176303389 , if you want tou can contact me on it.

Answer (score 0):

I was finaly able to get it done for IONIC 5 using the method below

ON .ts file i did it like this, using (ionChange)="segmentChanged($event)" on the ion-radio-group

category:any = "day";

then on HTML..hope it helps someone

```
          <ion-label>Select Biller</ion-label>
           <div class="cat-holder">
              <ion-radio-group (ionChange)="segmentChanged($event)" 
                  [value]="category">

              <div class="rad-item" text-center >
                <ion-item text-center>
                  <img src="assets/imgs/dstv.png" alt="">
                  <ion-radio value="transport" name="transport" ></ion-radio>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-label>Dstv</ion-label>
              </div>
              <div class="rad-item" text-center>
                <ion-item text-center>
                  <img src="assets/imgs/gotv.png" alt="">
                  <ion-radio value="Gotv" name="gotv" ></ion-radio>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-label>Gotv</ion-label>
              </div>


            </ion-radio-group>
          </div>
```